# How to save a column in a python variable

Tags: python, numpy

I've just started using python, and I've learned about np arrays. What I want to do is, to have an np column saved to a constant value. Example:

```
import numpy as np

SEA = np.array([:,4])
```

I'm making a 5x5 grid world and I want a value I can check that if the player lands anywhere in the 4th column they drown and fail, so I can check `if State == SEA: break` or something like that.

As it stands, the code above isn't correct when I tested it in the terminal. But is there a way to set a constant as a column or do I manually test `if State = [:, 4]`

TL;DR is there a way to save [:, 4] as a const variable

Comment: `world[:,4]` is the 4th column of array `world`.  `[:,4]` is not allowed as a stand alone object; it's only used to index an actual array.  You many need to review some basic Python syntax and `numpy` concepts.

Comment: if you really want to store a slice object, use `slice(None, 4)`, but you have to know what you're doing, which I don't think you do.

Comment: why don't you do `a[:,3] = your constant value`. And may be use `numpy.any(state == a[:,3])` to check whether player is on 4th column.

Comment: How do you create you numpy 5x5 array? It is not visible in the code above...

Comment: @AruneshSingh thanks, I'll try this

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I haven't read about slice yet. But somehow I don't think I want to store that. I'll read about it nonetheless

Comment: @mrCarnivore I make it using pandas DataFrame and initialized it to zero with np.zeros

Comment: @hpaulj so then I would just check manually in each iteration with if state == [: , 4] ?

Answer (score -1):

Consider this example code to get you started.

```
import numpy as np

SEA_COLUMN = 3
USER_POSITION_VALUE = 1

def is_user_in_sea(list_array):
    if USER_POSITION_VALUE in list_array[:, SEA_COLUMN]:
        print('In Sea')
    else:
        print('Safe')

list_array = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype = np.int32)
list_array[1][2] = USER_POSITION_VALUE
is_user_in_sea(list_array)
# Safe

list_array[4][SEA_COLUMN] = USER_POSITION_VALUE   # Not resetting the old value
is_user_in_sea(list_array)
# In Sea
```